# Add a line to a file if it not exist using python

Tags: python, xml

I have an xml file as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003" DefaultTargets="Build" ToolsVersion="4.0">
  <Import Project="$(VCTargetsPath)\Microsoft.Cpp.targets" />
  <ImportGroup Label="ExtensionTargets">
  </ImportGroup>
</Project>
```

I want to add a line `<Import Project="$(ProjectName).targets" />` between
`</ImportGroup>` and `</Project>` as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003" DefaultTargets="Build" ToolsVersion="4.0">
  <Import Project="$(VCTargetsPath)\Microsoft.Cpp.targets" />
  <ImportGroup Label="ExtensionTargets">
  </ImportGroup>
  <Import Project="$(ProjectName).targets" />
</Project>
```

If the line `<Import Project="$(ProjectName).targets" />` already exists in file there is no need to add.

How can I do that?

Comment: look into beautifulsoup or xmlDom

Comment: XML should not be interpreted in terms of lines, have a look at any of xml libraries (e.g. standard ElementTree)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is based on lines in text files, but the input file is clearly XML, so assuming you actually want to add an Import if it doesn't exist, try this:

```python
import xml.dom.minidom

importstring = "$(Projectname).targets"
filename = "test.xml"

tree = xml.dom.minidom.parse(filename)
Project = tree.getElementsByTagName("Project")[0]

for Import in Project.getElementsByTagName("Import"):
    if Import.getAttribute("Project") == importstring:
        break
else: # note this is else belongs to the for, not the if
    newImport = xml.dom.minidom.Element("Import")
    newImport.setAttribute("Project", importstring)
    Project.appendChild(newImport)

tree.writexml(open(filename, 'w'))
```

Comment: Thank you chthonicdaemon,

This helps me a lot.

Is there any way to give newline after an xml node

Comment: `writexml` takes an optional argument `newl` which allows you to specify line endings. On Windows you would use `tree.writexml(open(filename, 'w'), newl='\r\n')`. Probably a more portable option is to use `os.linesep`.

Answer (score 2):

Take the XML parser of your choice, parse the file, manipulate the file using the related API, write it back.