# Add a line to a text file if it not exist using python

Tags: python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Add a line to a file if it not exist using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12275255/add-a-line-to-a-file-if-it-not-exist-using-python)

I have a text  file as follows:

```
  <Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003" DefaultTargets="Build" ToolsVersion="4.0">
  <Import Project="$(VCTargetsPath)\Microsoft.Cpp.targets" />
  <ImportGroup Label="ExtensionTargets">
  </ImportGroup>
</Project>
```

I want to add a line `<Import Project="$(ProjectName).targets" />` between
`</ImportGroup>` and `</Project>` as follows

```
  <Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003" DefaultTargets="Build" ToolsVersion="4.0">
  <Import Project="$(VCTargetsPath)\Microsoft.Cpp.targets" />
  <ImportGroup Label="ExtensionTargets">
  </ImportGroup>
  <Import Project="$(ProjectName).targets" />
</Project>
```

I used fileinput module to insert the line but i don't want to add 
`<Import Project="$(ProjectName).targets" />` if it  already exists in file 
How can I do that?

Comment: no not a duplication 
it was an xml file but here iam asking for a text file and a text file can't be read using any of xml APIs.So i resposted it.I was able to add the line using Fileinput module and just asking you only about avoiding duplication

Comment: xml formatted files should be handled with an xml parser or html parser like xmlTree or Beautifulsoup...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12275255/add-a-line-to-a-file-if-it-not-exist-using-python ... no one...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should read the whole file, or enough lines and check if the substring is in the content with:

```
'<Import Project="$(ProjectName).targets" />' in file_content
```

Or you could use a regex to make the search more robust:

```
import re
regex = re.compile(r'<Import Project="\$\(ProjectName\)\.targets\s*/>')
if not regex.search(file_content):
    insert_line_into_file()
else:
    #the line already exists
```

Comment: Now, why a downvote without comment? I can't see this reply as "egregiously sloppy, no-effort-expended post, or an answer that is clearly and perhaps dangerously incorrect.", so it would have been better to comment or flag it if you[who downvoted] think that can be improved.

Answer (score 0):

With text as your file's text :

```
import re

match = = re.search( '\<ImportGroup Label="ExtensionTargets"\>', text )
text = text[:match.end()] +'<Import Project="$(ProjectName).targets" />\n'+ text[match.end():]
```